# add space between .net chart and lable

Tags: c#, charts

How can I move the labes down?

I would like to add some space between the chart and the labels. It is possible?

I'm using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

[image]

Like in this edited in mspaint:

[image]

Comment: What charting library are you using?

Comment: By default the labels will not touch the x-axis. What did you do to move them up so much??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will be **under the assumption** that you are using **CustomLabels on the X-axis**:

It is possible, but I am not *aware* of such a setting. But I can offer a pragmatic solution (*i.e. a bit of a hack*): Namely you reenable the gridtickmarks on the X-axis, but set Color to Transparent, after that you can adjust the distance to the axis by using MajorTickMark.Size (default 1), the **tick marks will not be visible**:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Size = 1;
// You can increase MajorTickMark.Size to increase distance to the axis
```

And incase someone *want* to have **both visible tickmarks and labels on an axis**:

Look into using `DataPoint.AxisLabel` in your series rather than using CustomLabels on the X-axis. `DataPoint.AxisLabel` will add a label on the axis for each datapoint. The axis-labels will then have the same distance to the axis as normal interval labels. There is a trick to it, that **if the first and last data point in a series have an AxisLabel set the axis interval numbers will be hidden** and leave only the axis labels.